# How do I obtain django default settings values NOT defined in my settings.py file?

Tags: python, django, django-settings

I must be missing something.

I'm trying to import DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE from the settings file.
I don't define it specifically in my settings.py file, but I was assuming that the default would be available.

When I add this variable to my settings.py it works fine, but when it's not there and I try to import I get an ImportError when using the development server via the runserver command:

```
from settings import DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE
ImportError: cannot import name DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE
```

Shouldn't I be able to do this without having to add it to *my* settings.py file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Never user `from settings import ...` or `import settings`. This will always only import your settings module, but not the whole Django settings.

Use `from django.conf import settings` instead in all your Django projects. This is using the Django Settings class which is a wrapper around all Django defined settings and your project settings from your settings file.

So for your example you would access `DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE` via `settings.DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE`.

Comment: Yes, as mentioned in [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/settings/#using-settings-in-python-code).

Comment: There they go hiding it in the documentation.  How do they expect anyone to find it *there*?

Answer (score 0):

`settings` is relative to your project, so it'll try to import `DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE` from *your* settings file. If you want to use Django's built-in `DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE` setting, you'd have to include it from their libraries (sorry, don't have Django installed on this machine, otherwise I'd look up the file that it's defined in).

Something like this:
`from django.some.settings.file import DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE`

You should be able to find it by just `grep`'ing through your Django lib dir.